# MASM moving array elements with nested loops

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86, masm

Initialize a BYTE array, not a 0 terminated string, with your last name. Using nested loops and indexed addressing, write a program that rotates the members of the array forward one position for each iteration of the outer loop. The value at the begining of the array must wrap around to the last position. For example, after the first iteration of the outer loop, 'S', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h' should be transformed to 'm', 'i', 't', 'h', 'S'. Display the array after each rotation using one of the author's library functions. Use the correct number of iterations of the outer loop to return the name to it's original spelling. The inner loop should perform the rotation.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out if someone could be of any assistance i would appreciate it. I'm very new to assembly and don't really know nested loops well. I also cannot figure out how to move the letters. This is what i have so far

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
WriteString PROTO

.data
    source BYTE "S", "m", "i", "t", "h"
.code
main PROC
    mov esi, 0
    mov ecx, SIZEOF source
L1 :
    mov al, source[esi]
    inc esi
loop L1
    mov edx, offset source 
    call WriteString
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: *"forward one position"*, then example moves them backward ('m' from second position to the first one)... ... Your short code does nothing meaningful (reads each original byte value once - sort of solid start, but like 5% of task), but it fails to use `WriteString` properly, because `WriteString` expects zero terminated string data (it probably works for you by accident I guess, finding some zero). From the task it's not clear whether defining one zero byte right after array for making `WriteString` correct is OK, or cheating - and you should instead print with `WriteChar` with another loop.

Answer (score 3):

> nested loops

keep in mind the whole "loop" is logical concept of programmer, not a feature of CPU (well, x86 does have instruction literally named `loop`, but rather do NOT use it: [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35742570/4271923)).

What makes a loop loop? You have some code which is considered "body" of loop, and you run it N-many times, that's "loop".

Now nested loops is calling a situation, where the body of loop (outer loop) contains another loop (inner loop), which will execute for example M-many times. Then the inner-loop body will execute NxM-many times in total, because each time the outer loop loops, the inner loop will run again.

Simple x86 example:

```
    ; init outer loop counter (will loop till zero)
    mov     ebp,7
outer_loop_body:
    ; some outer loop body code
    ; init inner loop counter (will loop till zero)
    mov     ecx,5
inner_loop_body:
    ; some inner (nested) loop body code
    ; this inner body will execute 7x5 = 35 many times
    dec     ecx
    jnz     inner_loop_body ; repeat until counter is zero
    ; some other outer loop code
    dec     ebp
    jnz     outer_loop_body ; repeat until counter is zero
    ; this code is outside of loops, executed after them
```

You must of course preserve your counters (if you run short on registers, use some memory to store them, if you don't use them too much).

In your task it is said *"indexed addressing"*, and the countdown counters in example goes through values N to 1, so they are almost usable as index (just needs -1), if you will start from the end of `source` array. But that is in favour of "forward one position" data movement with in-place memory overwrite, for backward move it would be better to construct loop which has up-count counter like:

```
    ; init loop index to go from zero to N-1
    xor     ecx,ecx     ; index = 0
loop_body:
    ; some loop body code, using ECX as index
    ; advance to next index
    inc     ecx
    cmp     ecx,N
    ; loop until value N in index is reached
    jb      loop_body
    ; this code is outside of loop, executed after it
```

> I also cannot figure out how to move the letters.

I would almost pay you to see what your brain tried, makes me really curious how you think about this kind of problems, for a seasoned programmer this is obvious, but looks like it is not.

I personally start with imagining the data (ignoring code and algorithm), in your case:

```
source BYTE "S", "m", "i", "t", "h"
```

This will assemble as 5 consecutive bytes in memory with values S, m, i, t, h (for particular numeric value check the ASCII table, or disassembly).

Now I imagine how the memory should look after first iteration of forward move (and I will do **forward** move):

```
source BYTE "h", "S", "m", "i", "t"
```

The "h" going off the original array is placed on the first position to make the whole content go round.

And now I imagine some algorithm to achieve this transformation of data (i.e. calculating the desired result from the input data):

```
fetch last element and keep it safe for later
loop (from last position down to second position) do:
    read position-1 element, and store it at position
store the original "last element" to first position
```

I run it quickly in my head to verify it does the calculation I want, fix any errors. I make some wild quick guess, how many instructions are needed to implement particular step, if it goes above cca 5, I break it down somewhat more to simpler steps. In this case this *feels* like each step is about 2-3 instructions (which usually means about x2 in the end), so this breakdown of algorithm would be ok for me.

Then I use that as base comments, and implement it with asm instructions.

Seems so obvious to me, that I can't imagine what made you stuck.

And finally example how to overwrite some memory of "array of bytes" in indexed way:

```
; assume ESI already contains address of array
; initialized earlier by something like: mov esi, OFFSET source
; and ECX contains index (0..4 value)
mov     al,[esi+ecx-1]    ; loads element from position ECX-1
    ; ^^ will go out of bounds for index 0!
mov     [esi+ecx],al      ; store that element to position ECX
```

Or you can use another MASM syntax option, this time specifying the array address directly as compile time constant:

```
; ECX contains index (0..4 value)
mov     al,source[ecx-1]    ; loads element from position ECX-1
    ; ^^ will go out of bounds for index 0
mov     source[ecx],al      ; store that element to position ECX
```

The first option with base address in register gives you option to re-use the same functionality over any memory array, not just the `source`, so I prefer it over the second variant, but otherwise they are identical in functionality.

So in short, "to move the letters" you simply overwrite the original memory content with the new content, which happens to be the original values, but stored to different addresses (by +-1, depending how you understand "forward" wording in question, although I believe that example is simply wrong, and "forward" is the other way around).

If you do that in-place in the same memory, notice you have to pick correct order of overwriting (either from last to first position for "forward", or form first to last position for "backward"), otherwise you will copy one element value into the remaining positions.

Now I would appreciate to hear what you were unable to figure out on this, and if it is clear now.

edit: one more note...

Of course to implement any calculation with asm instructions you need to have first some idea, what instructions are available, and what is their functionality. It helps to read through instruction reference guide few times to get a feel for what kind of calculation is possible.

With x86 I would start with the 80386 ISA, as that one is reasonably short (not including FP instructions and SIMD extensions), but already contains all common basic x86 instructions, for example google found some original PDF from Intel http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2013/readings/i386.pdf, chapters 3, 4, 5 and 17 relevant (or web version http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2014/readings/i386/c17.htm ).

And make sure you understand well what are CPU registers, how many of them there are, what are their "sizes" in bits, and what does that mean for min/max values, and what is computer memory and how does it operate. I.e. the basic things about x86 computer architecture.

Then the step "implement that comment with instructions" should be manageable (with growing experience even not that hard, as at first).

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for  equivalent question:

> Using a loop and indexed addressing, write code that rotates the members of a 32-bit integer
> array forward one position. The value at the end of the array must wrap around to the first position. For example, the array [10,20,30,40] would be transformed into [40,10,20,30]

```
COMMENT !
    Author : Tran Van Nam
    date: 23-Sep- 21
    Shifting the Element in an Array
    Ex8 Trang 138 assembly
!

.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096


ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword
.data
    array dword 1000h,20000h,30000h,40000h
.code
main proc
mov esi , offset  array     ;esi = point first element in array
mov eax, [esi]              ;
mov ecx, lengthof array -1  ; ecx :contain counter loop
mov edi, 0                  ; index 0 , element last changed
l1:
mov ebx,[esi+type array]        ; assigned EBX with next element 
mov [esi+type array], eax       ; rotate 2 element x and x+1
mov eax, ebx                  ;hold next element,so step previous is changed
add esi, type array             ; point to next element
loop l1

mov array[edi],eax
invoke ExitProcess , 0
main endp
end main
```

Thanks for watched

Comment: If you do `add esi, type array` first, you can omit the `+type array` offsets in the load and store.  Or start with `mov esi, offset array + type array` / `mov eax, [esi - type array]`.  But either way it's not a big deal.  Much more weird is using EDI at all.  You only ever set it to `0`, so `mov array[edi],eax` at the end could just be `mov array[0], eax` to store a new first element.   (Also, [the `loop` instruction is slow; generally avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction).  You could just `cmp esi, OFFSET array+sizeof array`/`jne l1` I think)

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is an English site; more people might find your answer useful if commented in English.  Other than those things I mentioned though, your code seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: Thank sir @PeterCordes for helpful comment  ❤